# How to display image in Notification other than app icon.[iOS]

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, swift2, apn

I Want to display Image in the push notification Banner Like the attached image.How can i achieve that.Can any one help.The screenshot is from an android mobile but i want the feature in iOS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you receive push notifications and your app is open (running in the foreground), you can make them have any appearance that you want by making your own views.

When push notifications are received and your app is closed, you are limited to how iOS displays system notifications.

The [Notifications section in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/NotificationCenter.html) provides a useful overview of the possibilities for handling push notifications.